# Grouping CSV columns in Apache Beam transform

Tags: apache-beam

I have a csv with about 200 columns. I would like to group each column such that I get a pcollection of col_name:[column] pairs as elements. How would such a thing be done using beam python sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output tuples of (column_index, column_value) then you can group them by the column index. If you have name associated with each column, then you can output (column_name, column_value).

Reference: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms